# Android StartActivityForResult bug

Tags: java, android

I have an android app which passes some results to the next activity using `StartActivityForResult`. This is working fine on every phone/tablet I've tested it on except for a `Motorola MZ601` which is on `Android 4.0.4`. By debugging through the code on any other device, it runs the below code:

```
private void showNextPage() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, InstructionsActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, TEST_LEFT_ACTIVITY);
}
```

This then takes me to the `onActivityResult` method as expected. Now when I debug through the code on the `Motorola` instead of taking to the `onActivityResult` method, it takes me to the `onCreate` method and reinitialises the results to `0` before moving to the `onActivityResult` method. So it passes `null` results over.

Can anyone explain to me why it takes me to the `onCreate` method before taking my to the `onActivityResult` method only on this device?

Is it a bug in the version of android or is it the device?

Comment: Maybe the caller activity get destroyed meanwhile?

Comment: I have an android app which passes some results to the next activity using `StartActivityForResult`. Is it possible?

Comment: well, the code works perfectly on every device I've tested it on except for this particular device? The code behaves different on this particular device and I can't figure out why, I'm assuming it's some sort of bug on the tablet of the android verion which is 4.0.4

Comment: Check the setting of device:: Setting-->developer option--> Do not keep activities (Disable it if enable).

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been trying to figure this out for 3 days, didn't even know there was a setting for this. Will defiantly be checking the setting first if I get an issue like this again!